# How do I hide or show content for each iteration?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a Lecture model which contains lectures. For each lecture I have a title and a content and eventually some files. I was trying to make that when somebody presses on a title, the title and the content will display under, but only for that lecture. Problem is that if I use a class, all lectures will be shown and if I use and id only the first one will be shown. How should I do this ?

```js
$('#title').click(function () {
            $('#lecture-hide').toggle();
        });
```

```html
 {% for c in category.list %}
                                    <div id="title">
                                        <p>Lecture {{ forloop.counter }}: <span>{{ c.lecture_title }}</span>
                                        </p>
                                        <br>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="lecture-hide" style="display: none;">
                                        <br>
                                        <li><h5>{{ c.lecture_title }}</h5></li>
                                        <li><p>{{ c.content }}</p></li>
                                        {% for file in c.files.all %}
                                            {% if file.files %}
                                                {% if forloop.first %}
                                                    <p id="files">Lecture files:</p>
                                                {% endif %}
                                                <li><a class="media"
                                                       href='{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ file.files.url }}'><i
                                                        class="fas fa-download"></i>{{ file.files.name }}</a></li>
                                            {% endif %}
                                        {% endfor %}
                                        <br>
                                    </div>
                                {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use `next` selector in your jQuery code like this:

```
$('div.title').click(function () {
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

You have to change id of the title to class to apply this to every element of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set dynamic attributes in your html:

```
{% for c in category.list %}
    <div class="title" id="title-{{ c.id }}">
        <!-- the content -->
    </div>

    <div class="lecture-hide" for="title-{{ c.id }}" style="display: none;">
        <!-- the content -->
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

and in JQuery

```
$('.title').click(function () {
    $('.lecture-hide[for="title-' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').toggle();
});
```

This will works even if the html elements order change.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the above one was first and easier. I'm sure this is good as well, but I have to vote that one as best.